# Linux background process

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, linux, background-process

I am lost in what can be a simple problem, but I'm afraid that I need that some one gives me a little light to follow.

I have right now a Linux server, with a PHP app running, and I want to create a process that runs continuously in the background, checking the content of a MySQL table, and performing actions depending on that content.

Before, I had it in .NET C#. The approach was the following:

- ASP.NET MVC site that takes user input and actions.
- C# .NET background process that every 2 minutes fetches the new record of one table (called operations), perform that actions and flag them as SUCCEED or FAILED.

The new approach, to switch to Linux and save money in servers, is:

- PHP site that takes user input and actions
- **Whatever that let me do the same as I did with the background process in C#.**

Any direction of language, workflow or how to achieve that?

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a classic cronjob, not? You can run a PHP script via shell either via "wget http://..." or "php -f file.php"

Comment: Write a PHP script that does what you need to do, then schedule it with cron.

Comment: I understand that this will run directly to php, without affecting apache, and therefore, without affecting too much to the website performance, right?
Can I, somehow, limit how many RAM can that PHP Process consume?

Comment: Yep, it's a simple ini setting that you can put at the top of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Cron job is what you'll need to look at for scheduling script/program to run regularly. Language is really up to you.